# Is there a "Sum of range" concept in Math and if so what does it stands for?

Tags: calculus, statistics, terminology, arithmetic

I am not a mathematician but I've came across the concept "sum of range" in the past → I don't recall where exactly.

I didn't find a relevant Wiki article, nor some basic conceptual data on this in a quick search or some statistics introduction books I have read.

Is there a "Sum of range" concept in Math and if so what does it stands for?
That is to ask; is this an existing formal math concept and if so, what main problem or problems it is used to solve?

Comment: Perhaps $\sum_{i=n}^m i$ could be the *sum of the range $n$ to $m$*?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the sum of numbers from 1 to n it's $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) is the article for it.

Comment: For example, 2*(2+1)/6=3 right? If I understood correctly, please only tell me, to what kind of computation it is usually applied as a forumla?